# C/C++ Bitwise Operations not resulting in expected output?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm currently working on bitwise operations but I am confused right now... Here's the scoop and why

I have a byte `0xCD` in bits this is `1100 1101`
I am shifting the bits left 7, then I'm saying `& 0xFF` since `0xFF` in bits is `1111 1111`

```
unsigned int bit = (0xCD << 7) & 0xFF<<7;
```

Now I would make the assumption that both `0xCD` and `0xFF` would get shifted to the left 7 times and the remaining bit would be `1&1 = 1` but I'm not getting that for output also I would also make the assumption that shifting 6 would give me bits `0&1 = 0` but I'm getting again a number above 1 like 205 0.o Is there something incorrect about the way I am trying to process bit shifting in my head? If so what is it that I am doing wrong?

Code Below:

```
unsigned char byte_now = 0xCD;
printf("Bits for byte_now: 0x%02x: ", byte_now);
/*
* We want to get the first bit in a byte.
* To do this we will shift the bits over 7 places for the last bit
* we will compare it to 0xFF since it's (1111 1111) if bit&1 then the bit is one
*/
unsigned int bit_flag = 0;
int bit_pos = 7;
bit_flag = (byte_now << bit_pos) & 0xFF;
printf("%d", bit_flag);
```

Comment: `printf("%d, bit_flag);"` means you want to print a **signed** integer, but you are passing an **unsigned** one

Comment: When you shift anything to the left, the LSB is becoming zero. How can it be `1`?

Comment: The `0xCD << 7` (binary `1100 1101`) results in `0x80` (binary `1000 0000`) as does `0xFF << 7`.

Comment: @WeatherVane  `0xCD << 7` results in binary `0110 0110 1000 0000` with some amount of leading zeroes  . (Arithmetic is always done in at least `int` width)

Comment: The question is unclear; in the first line you use `0xFF << 7` as the mask but in the "Code Below" you use `0xFF` in the mask. Which is it?

Comment: @M.M true: the variable shifted is `unsigned char byte_now = 0xCD;` but is placed in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: This code and even the question is flawed for what I was doing in many ways... I didn't have the understanding to even begin to read what I was writing I know about basic arthmetic with left shift, and right shift but before this post, that was about all I knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something incorrect about the way I am trying to process bit shifting in my head?

There seems to be.

> If so what is it that I am doing wrong?

That's unclear, so I offer a reasonably full explanation.

In the first place, it is important to understand that C does not not perform any arithmetic directly on integers smaller than `int`.  Consider, then, your expression `byte_now << bit_pos`.  "The usual arithmetic promotions" are performed on the operands, resulting in the left operand being converted to the `int` value `0xCD`.  The result has the same pattern of least-significant value bits as `bit_flag`, but also a bunch of leading zero bits.

Left shifting the result by 7 bits produces the bit pattern `110 0110 1000 0000`, equivalent to `0x6680`.  You then perform a bitwise and operation on the result, masking off all but the least-significant 8 bits, thus yielding `0x80`.  What happens when you assign that to `bit_flag` depends on the type of that variable, but if it is an integer type that is either unsigned or has more than 7 value bits then the assignment is well-defined and value-preserving.  Note that it is bit **7** that is nonzero, not bit 0.

The type of `bit_flag` is more important when you pass it to `printf()`.  You've paired it with a `%d` field descriptor, which is correct if `bit_flag` has type `int` and incorrect otherwise.  If `bit_flag` *does* have type `int`, then I would expect the program to print 128.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and you are right, the yeilding result was 0x80.  I'll have to play around some more, but one more quick question in regards to your explanation, you said that one the product is shifted 7 times to left it yeilds '0110 0110 1000 0000' are the first 8 bits just for refrence?

Comment: the first 8 bits are part of the `int`. On 32-bit systems, one should even write `0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0110 1000 0000`

Comment: @TheStart101, no, the first 8 bits are *not* just for reference.  This is an important implication of the fact, covered specifically in this answer, that the expression is evaluated as an operation on a value of type `int`.  I guess I was not explicit that the *result* is an `int`, too.  I have omitted the leading zeroes, but `int` is *at least* 16 bits wide on every conforming C implementation, and it is commonly 32 bits wide on today's general-purpose computers.  The leading bits shown are a *bona fide* part of the result of the shift.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, You helped me a great deal with this information, I was under the assumption that by shifting them left, they where gone, I was working with bytes from a hex file I made, and for some reason I chose int over char while working with the bytes, which caused many issues that I didn't understand until this answer. I am marking this as solved with your answer, Thanks again!